# WebSphere datasource test connection fails with SQLServer Windows Authentication

Tags: windows-authentication, sql-server-2016, websphere-8

Test connection fails with SQL Server Windows Authentication.
Below are the setting i have done.

1. Copied sqljdbc_auth.dll in ${WAS_INSTALL_ROOT}/java/bin
2. Set URL jdbc:sqlserver://mbaastest31.konylabs.net:1433;databasename=konyadmindb2805181519;integratedSecurity=true;
3. Added ${WAS_INSTALL_ROOT}/java/bin jdbc provider native library path
   4.As this is WORKGROUP machine J2c user id given as WIN-MDP5BJ0RCA3\administrator where WIN-MDP5BJ0RCA3 is hostname
4. I have tried only providing uid as administrator in J2c which didn't work

How to get successful connection in case of WORKGROUP?

Below is the error when test connection

> The test connection operation failed for data source
>   konyadmindb2805181519dsnameForserver1 on server server1 at node
>   WIN-KLGMU5KFTR2Node01  with the following exception:
>   java.sql.SQLException: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS
>   LOGON'. ClientConnectionId:aae688ec-1fe4-4a6f-8f6c-7faf0df95c29
>   DSRA0010E: SQL State = S0001, Error Code = 18,456. View JVM logs for
>   further details.

Referred [Connect to SQL Server using Windows Authentication](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21584489)

Thanks,
Kusuma

Comment: As far as I know, SQL Server Windows Authentication requires a domain environment, rather than just a Workgroup.

Comment: @T-Heron Will try that having Domain